# How to render a list in react when list data part of larger data set

Tags: reactjs, jsx, prismic.io

I'm new to React and JSX and stuck on how to render a list of items, given that the data source is multiple data types.

My data source (prismic) returns an array of data, all different types, that each represent a html tag
E.g. data from server is:

```
heading3 (h3)  
paragraph (p)  
list-item (li for ul)  
list-item (li for ul)  
list-item (li for ul)  
paragraph (p)  
o-list-item (li for ol)  
o-list-item (li for ol)  
paragraph (p)
```

I want to convert this to valid HTML, inserting the data returned.

```
E.g. heading3 will render <h3>heading_text</h3>
```

The data does not contain an entry for the opening and closing tags of a list, so I need to insert them when a list starts and finishes.

My first attempt was to do something like this:

```
    renderSectionText(alltextdata) {
    let texthtml = [];
    let listopen = false;
    alltextdata.map((text, index) => {
        switch (text.type) {
            case "heading3":
               //if a ul/ol started, end one (insert a closing ul/ol tag)
               if(listopen){
                    texthtml.push(</ul>)
                    listopen = false;
               }
                texthtml.push(<h3 key={index}>{text.text}</h3>);
                break;
            case "paragraph":
                if(listopen){
                    texthtml.push(</ul>)
                    listopen = false;
                }
                //if a ul/ol started, end one (insert a closing ul/ol tag)
                texthtml.push(<p key={index}>{text.text}</p>);
                break;
            case "list-item":
                //if no ul/ol started, start one (insert an opening ul/ol tag)
                if(listopen === false){
                    texthtml.push(<ul>)
                    listopen = true;
                }
                texthtml.push(<li key={index}>{text.text}</li>);
                break;

            default:
                console.log(text.type);
                return;
          }
    })
    return texthtml;
}
```

But, it's not possible in React (AFAIK) to enter a tag without a closing one. 
i.e. this gives me a JSX syntax error

```
            case "list-item":
                //if no ul/ol started, start one 
                if(listopen === false){
                   texthtml.push(<ul>);   //error here                       
                   listopen = true;
                }
                texthtml.push(<li key={index}>{text.text}</li>);
                break;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, React and JSX simply do not work that way. When you create an HTML node it needs to include the closing tag or be self closing.

Instead, when you come across something that should be an `<li>`, start pushing them into an array. When you come across the next non-`<li>` item, wrap all of your `<li>`s in an `<ol>` or `<ul>`, and then push *that* into your `texthtml`.

Some pseudocode:

```
let texthtml = [];
let listItems = [];
alltextdata.forEach((ea, i) => {
  if(ea.type === "list-item"){
    listItems.push(<li key={i} >{ea.text}</li>);
  } else {
    if(listItems.length > 0){
      texthtml.push(<ul key={i} >{listItems}</ul>);
      listItems = [];
    }
    // Continue with process other non-list-items here...
  }
})
```

Pssst you should be using `forEach` not `map` since you're strictly iterating over the array and not actually mapping it into a new array. `if-else` will also be a bit better than a `switch` IMO because it will help avoid repeating your code like you have now.

Comment: Doh! Of course. I had a suspicion the solution would involve another list, but could just not see it at the time. Thanks for the other tips too.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running your own backend I would have your own restful endpoint reach the data and you can transform/parse the way you want then have your front end touch your node/w.e backend you're running to get a better structured data. I don't know if that's ideal for your case but whenever I had to an api give me information and it came back nasty i'd speak to my backend team and be like cmon guys or you can parse it yourself using your node/w.e server.

from the sounds of it you will need to construct something more malleable or useable i definitely recommend parsing in another service.

Else have fun with the data being parsed on the front end Q_Q...

Good luck I hope this helps and it seems like it's going to be alot of trial and error to see if you're getting your data correctly returned to you and have it loaded to the dom :)

If anyone else has better solution would love to learn more about it!~ :)

Comment: my use case for this was when I was trying to implemented a pretemplated inbox service on the backend the data was straight up strings and a nasty looking case by case removing unnecessary characters

Comment: The data is from a headless CMS (prismic) and is returned as a graphQL result. The site is a gatsby generated one which uses a source plugin to get the data from Prismic. Looks like I'll have to write a gatsby transformer to transform the data into something nice. I was hoping to avoid that for now.

Comment: ahhh yeah seems like it's going to be some sort of transform yeah it sucks thanks <:) GL

You know what message prismic ask them if they got some sort of process that could help you for parsing the data :)